# What is the grammatical function of "knowing" in the sentence "he's grown up knowing your name."?

Tags: participle-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses, secondary-predicates

Is the following a reduced form?

> He's grown up knowing your name.

If yes, what has the original form been?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a 'reduced' form.

*Knowing* here acts here in its participial capacity, not gerundial, so the phrase/clause *knowing your name* acts as an adjectival. Syntactically it is a 'secondary subject complement': a non-obligatory predicative complement of the verb which identifies or characterizes the subject. An ordinary adjective or noun phrase could play the same role:

> He grew up very poor.
>   He grew up a beggar.

You could paraphrase

> He grew up, and all the time he was growing up he knew your name.

But don't mistake this paraphrase for a 'fuller' form of the construction.

Comment: Adjectival? I don't think so. It's not a modifier, it looks like it's an adjunct. And function of "knowing" is Predicator, I guess.

Comment: @Man_From_India - Indeed, *knowing* is a predicator. But adjectivals are not always modifiers: they may also act as predicative complements, as in *He is poor*. This use bears the name "predicative" because it "predicates" something of the subject, as the clause *knowing his name* does here.

Comment: yes *nods*. I actually meant that it looked like an Adverbial, rather than an adjectival.

Comment: @Man_From_India - It doesn't attribute a quality or manner to the action of growing up, it attributes a state to the subject of growing up. *He grew up knowledgeable*, not *He grew up knowledgeably.*

Comment: mmmm but unlike a predicative complement, we can move this non-finite clause around, without affecting the sentence whatsoever.

Comment: @Man_From_India - I think not. If you move it before or immediaely after the subject it implies "He knew your name and consequently grew up", which is an entirely different assertion.

Comment: the meaning could be ambiguous, but syntactically we can move it around. We can say *eating popcorn we watched the whole match* and *we watched the whole match eating popcorn* without having any difference in meaning.

Answer (score 2):

> *He's grown up [knowing your name].*

No, it's not a reduced form.

You specifically asked what the grammatical function of "knowing" is. The simple answer is that its function is **head**, more specifically head of the bracketed gerund-participial clause.

I take the subordinate clause to be an adjunct, since it can be freely omitted, though I'm not sure what semantic category it belongs in.

Comment: But "head" is for a phrase, not for a clause. I didn't get it.

Comment: @Man_From_India The head of a clause is a verb phrase, and the head of a verb phrase is a verb, so it follows that the head of a clause is a verb!

Comment: but the head of this clause is still the implied subject. Or else it would sound like a clause consisting of just a phrase. In that case why would we call it a clause, not simply a phrase?

Comment: @Man_From_India No. A subject is never head of a clause. "Knowing your name" is a non-finite clause and most non-finite clauses are subjectless, though we can retrieve the subject from the matrix clause --, in this case it's clearly "he".

Comment: well, I shouldn't have used the term "head". Because I have objection to the term "head" in the context of clause.